# How implement pub/sub google with listen serve

Tags: go

The problem is when I need to get the pub / sub messages from google and have a rest api running at the same time

```
err = client.Subscription("my-sub").Receive(ctx, func(ctx context.Context, msg *pubsub.Message) {

    var data Data
    json.Unmarshal(msg.Data, &data)
    msg.Ack()
})
log.Printf("connect to http://localhost:%s/ for api Rest", port)
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, nil))
```

Comment: You said when the problem happens, but not what it is. Is it that `Receive` does not return? If that's the case, run it in a goroutine.

Comment: thanks, it worked for me using the goroutine.

Answer (score 0):

"The callback is invoked concurrently by multiple goroutines, maximizing throughput. To terminate a call to Receive, cancel its context." - from https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/pubsub?tab=doc

It sounds like you want a REST API that provides clients the ability to request previously received Pub/Sub messages (msg.Data)

"Package http provides HTTP client and server implementations." - from https://pkg.go.dev/net/http?tab=doc#example-Handle

You will need to store or cache the msg's received from Pub/Sub so they are available to send to your HTTP client when they make HTTP requests.